# How to debug "warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node."

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to trace the location of `process.nextTick` being called recursively? E.g. in this case,

```
var normal = function(cb) {
    process.nextTick(cb);
}

var bad = function() {
    process.nextTick(bad);
};

normal(function() {
    bad();
});
```

That the problem is on line 5 in function "bad"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the node command line switch `--throw-deprecation` to turn the warning into a thrown exception, which will give you a stack trace to debug from.